# Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() even though I stopped the service

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

So my app has some remote actions that trigger a service and notification. Between the call to `startForegroundService` and the time the service tries to start the notification things could change so the service once again checks the state of things and then decides what to do.

So if my service decides it doesn't need to run it will call:

```
stopForeground(true);
stopSelf();
```

But for some reason this doesn't seem to work because I get this exception almost immediately after making those calls.

```
11-16 13:34:23.488 15099-15099/mypackage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: mypackage, PID: 15099
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

So how can I solve this?

Thanks.

Edit:

I created a sample project that all it does is call `startForegroundService` when the Activity starts and then it does this on the service:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG,"start");
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

And it crashes, whether I use `stopForeground(true)` or not.

Edit: This seems to fix it, but seems really ugly to have to create a fake notification just to cancel it.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG,"start");
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)

                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");

        startForeground(-1,mBuilder.build());
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

Comment: Try calling `startForeground()` immediately before `stopForeground()` and `stopSelf()`.

Comment: How about simply calling `stopSelf()`? If a `Service` is stopped I think (ok, I guess) it will not be in the foreground any more.

Comment: To start foreground I need a notification, don't I? I'll try the stop self on its own.

Comment: I just read the documentation for [startForegroundService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)). Maybe your Service really has to do that startForeground() call before doing anything else because it looks like some kind of contract: "The service is given an amount of time comparable to the ANR interval to do this, otherwise the system will automatically stop the service and declare the app ANR. "

Comment: @0X0nosugar tried it, still crashes. I updated my post.

Comment: @CommonsWare so calling `startForeground` fixes it but I have to a create a fake notification for that. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: I doubt it. IMHO, this is a bug -- `stopSelf()` prior to the ANR timeout should eliminate the need to raise the notification. You're welcome to file an issue for it, with a repeatable test case, and hope that they fix it in some future version of Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare got a response already and status changed to won't fix. This is the intended behavior. Response from them: `Once you have called startForegroundService, your service is running as a foreground service, and you have bypassed background restrictions.  You are thus under contractual obligation to show a notification to go along with the foreground service.  This is intended for cases where you know that you need to run in the foreground and will do that for a significant reason (for example the user pressing the headset button to start music playback).`

Comment: Note that you don't need to call `startForegroundService()` just to use `startForeground()`. You only need it if you are in the background at the time and the event is not triggered from one of a handful of allowed sources (e.g., notification action).

Comment: Most of the time I'm probably not on the background, so I could do a check and use the normal `startService` when I'm not in the background. Is there a way to check if I'm on the background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem and I use the same workaround before stopSelf():

```
private void fakeStartForeground() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setContentTitle("")
                        .setContentText("");

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

I think that somebody form Google should give us some solution. Have you posted in Google Bugs reporting forum?

Comment: I filed a bug and they said that once you call the start foreground service method you enter a contract where you must create a notification. I'm using the same workaround as you.

Comment: @Mateusz Kaflowski can you provide full example.